# Correct way to set up multiple VMs with Hyper-V on a remote server with one physical interface?

Tags: hyper-v, nat, windows-server-2019

I have a Windows Server 2019 host on a remote server with four allocated IPs, a /30 CIDR block, with one of those publicly facing and one acting as the gateway. I think what I'm looking to achieve is to create a NAT to provision internal IP addresses, which multiple Hyper-V VMs can use to access the internet.

Let's say the machine's been allocated `25.50.75.72/30`, giving it the following addresses:

- `25.50.75.72`
- `25.50.75.73` (gateway)
- `25.50.75.74` (public)
- `25.50.75.75` (broadcast)

Is there a way to create a NAT on an internal vSwitch that provisions its own block of IP addresses (e.g. `10.0.0.0/24`), and allows those internet access through one of the physical interface? Or is an ideal solution something else entirely?

Edit: I'm looking to gain an understanding of which addresses I should map to what, and why.

Comment: The `192.0.0.0/24` address block is reserved for IETF protocol assignments, and those addresses cannot be used. See the _[IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml)_

Comment: My mistake - but it was just an example range. Updated the question with a private use block.

Comment: I assumed it was an example, but I wanted to make sure. Notice, too, the IANA site has ranges for example addresses: `192.0.2.0/24`, `198.51.100.0/24`, and `203.0.113.0/24`. In this case, a Private address range, such as you have edited, is probably the most appropriate.

Comment: You can create a NAT virtual switch in Hyper-V in Windows 10, Windows Server 2016, and Windows Server 2019.